# Too many re-renders React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**I need to put a value to the state inside a method map. But get this error, how can I fix this? Thank you.**

[image]

```
const Cart = () => {
    const { value, setValue } = useContext(UserContext)
    const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(0)

    const setPrice = (newValue) => {
            setTotalPrice(totalPrice + newValue)
            console.log(totalPrice)
    }
    console.log(value)

    if (value == false) {
            return (
                    <h1>Cart is empty</h1>
            )
    } else {

            return (

                    <div>
                            {
                                    value.map(product => {


                                            return <>
                                                    <ProductToCart name={product[0]} img={product[1]} discription={product[2]} price={product[3]} />
           set state here ---->                     {setPrice(Number(product[3] + ))}
                                            </>

                                    })

                            }
                    </div>

            )
    }
```

**There is a value in the props, so I want to calculate the total price for all products, and need to set the product prices into State :**
[image]

Comment: You should just calculate total price once, you could use value.reduce for that

Comment: Do not update state inside the return statement as it'll rerender and lead to infinite loop

Comment: Look this answer [to-many rerenders react](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457575/1457588#1457588) May by it help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use react `useMemo` hook to calculate the totalPrice. I don't think you need to use the `useState` hook.

```
const totalPrice = React.useMemo(()=>{
    return value.reduce((acc, product)=>{
        acc +=Number(product?.[3] ?? "0");
        return acc;
    }, 0)
}, [value])
```